# How use variable in the path while import typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to put a varible(or a const) to the path instead of writting whole path as string literal. As it seems, angular doesn't accept anything but string literal.

```
import aClass = require("./simpleClass"); 
import { aComponent } from aClass.myClass.Root + 'tutorial.component';
```

myClass:

```
export class myClass{    
    public static Root = "./"
}
```

In this example `aClass.myClass.Root + 'tutorial.component'` has error which was explained

Comment: _"has error which is explained"_ what error?

Comment: Compiler says that path should be literal string

Comment: `aClass.myClass.Root` is `undefined`... Instead use `aClass.Root`? Although I still don't think that will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it does support dynamic imports now..

just do this

```
async () => {
  const { aComponent } = await import(aClass.myClass.Root + 'tutorial.component');
}
```

for more information

http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html

Try this

```
import aClass from "./simpleClass"; 
var aComponent = require(aClass.myClass.Root + 'tutorial.component').aComponent;
```

or

```
import { myClass } from './simpleClass';
const { aComponent } = require(myClass.Root + 'tutorial.component');
```

Comment: It works, thanks! @siamak-ferdos that should be an accepted answer

Comment: Works great in Angular! `import { env } from 'environments'; export function getsomejson(){ return 'assets/path/' + env.some_var + '/file.json' }` and then in the `component.ts` you just: `import {getsomejson} from 'path'; ... style = getsomejson();`, and in the `html` you just need: `[style]="style | async"`