# How to import javascript from filename variable?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to import javascript from a filename stored in a variable to be determined at runtime, something like below?

```
const mydir="./bobs_pictures.js"
import pictures from mydir;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6/TypeScript Dynamic Imports - Slow launch time because of static imports (Nodejs CLI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306937/es6-typescript-dynamic-imports-slow-launch-time-because-of-static-imports-nod)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How use variable in the path while import typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468624/how-use-variable-in-the-path-while-import-typescript)

Comment: If you're talking about frontend, different bundlers have different methods of achieving wildcard imports (e.g. `require.context` for Webpack, `import.meta.glob` for Vite/Esbuild).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports), which run asynchronously.

```
const importPromise = import(mydir);
importPromise.then((module) => {
  // do something
});
```

If you want to use it across a function / module, note that it must be an async function, and then you'll be able to use it in a regular way with `await`:

```
async () => {
  const mydir = "./bobs_pictures.js";
  const module = await import(mydir);
}
```

PS. please check browser compatibility. You might need to use an external tool in order to run this on older browsers.